# Can we copy "nowinandroid" android source code from github and customise it according my app needs?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I see that "[nowinAndroidApp](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid)" has all the best practices and has many generic common modules like database, restapi, connectivitystatus and preferences for an app to be developed from scratch in compose now a days. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, Can I copy and customise according to my own application needs?

I have searched many places to learn jetpack compose in real time projects. However I see that "nowinandroid" only meets my expectation.

Comment: You should check with a Lawyer on how to comply with the License https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/LICENSE (So this question is not suitable for Stackoverflow)

Comment: @Andrew , thanks for prompt reply. Yes I saw this License already, but I have posted in SO to see if anyone else is already in my shoes.

Answer (score 0):

**Now In Android** app is for reference purposes.

I suggest you to check its source code and implement it in your code. Because if any issues arises, you need to have knowledge to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I raised https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/issues/967.  will follow as per Apache License..  thanks @Surya